# Parsing a String [] of csv's

Tags: java, arrays, csv

I am trying to take the info from a string array that each string in the array is a csv, like so:

```
        String[] jobs     = { 
            "2,-8,4",       
            "10,-10,9,-3", 
            "9,-1" 
        }
```

I know how to take csv from a file, but i dont understand how to take these values from the string and get their int forms amd put them into an array. I was thinking i can all just put them in 1 array.

Comment: `split` every array element by `,`, then add it to an int array with `Integer.parseInt(value)`

Comment: You have an array of 3 Strings. Pull out each String and split it on the `,`. Then parse the results into ints.

Comment: Try something!!  Look at the String spec and pick a one or two likely functions to try.

Comment: thanks i wasnt looking for code rude people, just an idea of where to srart

Comment: Start with the String spec.  Read it and see if you don't see some functions that might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you really need to do is split the strings and parse to int.

```
List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
// For each element in jobs array
for (int i = 0; i < jobs.length; i++)
    // For each csv in current element
    for (String s : jobs[i].split(","))
        ints.add(Integer.parseInt(s)); // parse and add to ints

for (int i : ints)
    System.out.println(i);
```

Comment: thanks man, i was struggling with the arrays since there are different arrays each with different lengths of info, An array list is what i needed. ill take what you provided and adapt it to my code, thanks!